# testNg classes launch order

Tags: java, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a java - maven -project with multiple modules.
In each module, I have mock tests and tests using database.
Mock tests names end with "Test" and database tests end with "IT".
UserTest and UserIT for example, are in the same package and in the same module.

I'd like to run first all mock tests, then all database tests.
is there a way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: the problem/question is regarding multi-module!? You want `Test`s before `IT`s for *all* modules? (since module-wise it's the "default order")

Comment: I want for each module, that the Test run before the IT.
(Module 1 runs Tests then ITs, Module 2 runs Tests then ITS, etc.)
I would like to have a common configuration across modules.

Comment: please have a look at [Maven-Failsafe-Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) (?)

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at it. Thx

Comment: so a `mvn failsafe:integration-test` ([normally...bound to "integration-test" lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html) ) implies passed "test" phase/surefire plugin. ..and: the failsafe-plugin [(by default) includes `*IT.java` name pattern](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) ..whereas [surefire includes (.i.a.) `*Test.java`](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire-archives/surefire-LATEST/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Comment: Yes, it works fine ! Thx